# I created rails g controller admin/post and it is looking for admin/posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Going to:

localhost/admin/post/

I get the error:

```
uninitialized constant Admin::PostsController
```

Yet the generated controller is:

```
class Admin::PostController < ApplicationController
```

Notice the error has an 's' but the class generated doesn't.

My routes are:

```
namespace :admin do
     resource :post
  end
```

But rake routes shows:

```
admin_post POST   /admin/post(.:format)                  {:controller=>"admin/posts", :action=>"create"}
     new_admin_post GET    /admin/post/new(.:format)              {:controller=>"admin/posts", :action=>"new"}
    edit_admin_post GET    /admin/post/edit(.:format)             {:controller=>"admin/posts", :action=>"edit"}
                    GET    /admin/post(.:format)                  {:controller=>"admin/posts", :action=>"show"}
                    PUT    /admin/post(.:format)                  {:controller=>"admin/posts", :action=>"update"}
                    DELETE /admin/post(.:format)                  {:controller=>"admin/posts", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html):

> Because you might want to use the same
>   controller for a singular route
>   (/account) and a plural route
>   (/accounts/45), singular resources map
>   to plural controllers.

When you run the generator, you should provide a pluralized name:

```
rails g controller admin/posts
```

Answer (score 1):

When using map.resources, it expects plural names. Try passing in :controller => :post as an option.

Answer (score 0):

wmorgan is correct as to why the default didn't work as you expected. To fix it, you can either:

1. rename the controller to Admin::PostsController (and rename the file too)
2. update all the routes to point to :controller=>"admin/post" instead